# $wpdb->insert is adding 3 rows at once

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin and on action wp_head it executes a function that inserts to a custom DB table one row. But it is actually adding 3 rows at the time.

Any Ideas?

```
global $post;
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin_table";


echo "<!-- ID: ". $post->ID . ", TYPE: " . get_post_type($post->ID) . " -->";

$data = array( 'post'  => $post->ID, 'type'  => get_post_type($post->ID) );
$format = array( '%d', '%s');


if( $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data, $format ) ){
  echo "<!-- RESULT:: ADDED: ". $wpdb->insert_id . " -->";
}
```

It echo's one line of each echo but it adds to the DB table 3 rows, where in one of them the post ID is different.

Comment: can you tell me how you add wp_head action and where you put wp_head action?

Comment: Yes I can. This function belongs to a class and add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_to_custom_table') is inside __construct function.

Comment: Is the class where you keep this code is singleton?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand @Nilambar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this way

```
 function add_to_custom_table() 
    {
        if ( is_single() ) 
        {
                  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin_table";

                   echo "<!-- ID: ". get_the_ID . ", TYPE: " . get_post_type($post->ID) . " -->";

    $data = array( 'post'  => get_the_ID(), 'type'  => get_post_type(get_the_ID()) );
    $format = array( '%d', '%s');


             if( $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data, $format ) )
             {
               echo "<!-- RESULT:: ADDED: ". $wpdb->insert_id . " -->";
             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: with is_single() one of the rows is gone. The one that had the post id different. So now it's adding two rows instead of one.

Comment: can you tell me which theme you are using it

Comment: It is from the theme, because I tried it in a different wordpress theme and it works perfectly. Thank You guys!!!!